# Convert callback code to promise

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to use the bluebird libarary and my question is how to convert the following code to bluebird promise

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'npm install morgan --save';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if(error || stderr){
        console.error(error);
        console.error(stderr);
        console.log("test");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, **DO NOT** use the promise constructor. Please. I've lost tens of hours debugging code where people missed *this just one thing*.

Bluebird will gladly promisify things for you automatically, it will do it faster and make it easier to debug.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var exec = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
var cmd = 'npm install morgan --save';
exec(cmd).spread(function(stdout, stderr){
    // access output streams here    
    console.log(stdout, stderr); // output both stdout and stderr here
}).catch(function(error){
    // handle errors here
});
```

In the future we have a canonical reference for converting things to promises. There is also a [list of how-tos here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification).

Comment: Thanks 1+ ,3 questions :) why you use spread? 2. how I add the error handling,can you please show in the answer ?in the previos example it was with reject...3 how do call it..

Comment: I use `spread` because I want to get both `stdout` and `stderr` (if I only wanted stdout I would have done `.get(0)` to get the first item). About error handling - you'd just attach a `.catch` handler (after the spread or before it depending on what you want to handle and how) - just like with any other promise code.

Comment: DO you mean like this     exec(cmd).spread(function(stdout, stderr){
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    });

Comment: if yes how should I get the stderr ? 2. how to invoke this all operation ?

Comment: Just like in the answer, it's just the second parameter of the `spread`

Comment: It doesnt work for me can you please update the answer with it ? 2. and how to invoke this operation ?thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated, but this is getting off topic, if you don't know how to use a bluebird feature please open a separate question. This one is how to convert the API to use promises which is what this answer does.

Comment: Hi Benjamin,two last question :)  assume I wan to use then to do addtional thing how should I do it with your example?2.regard the error which error I'll get in the catch the stderr ?

Answer (score 0):

quite simple, just use the bluebird promise constructor:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'npm install morgan --save';

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(error || stderr)   return reject(error || stderr);  
        return resolve(stdout);
    }); 
});


promise
  .then(console.log.bind(console))      //success handler
  .catch(console.log.bind(console))     // failure handler
```

Comment: Thanks 1+,if I want to use the promisifyAll can you please add additional example how to adopt the code ?

Comment: @Mark, just now I looked at the `child_process` methods, not all use callbacks, some return child_process objects, I am not sure how bluebird's promisifyAll would handle that, but you can give [child-process-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promisel) a try

Comment: wait for a while, Bergi or Benjamin would come along and give me satisfactory answer :)

Comment: To be 100% honest, the promisification here looks correct, although it behaves differently from how one would initially expect - rejecting on stderr output.